# Why are my class elements created by javascript undefined when i try to acess them by their class name?

Tags: javascript

I created a link node with javascript, appended it to the `body` and gave it a class of 'heart'.

They are visible in the browser and when I inspect, I can see that they have the class name 'heart'.

However, when I try to access them by the method `getElementsByClassName` and `console.log()` the resuly, it returns all of them as `undefined`, as if they don't exist.

Here is my whole code:

```js
body.appendChild(imagebox);

for (var i = 9; i <= 16; i++) {

  var imagebox = document.createElement("div");
  imagebox.classList.add("imagebox");
  
  var heart = document.createElement("a");
  heart.innerHTML = "&#10084;";
  
  heart.classList.add("heart");
  imagebox.appendChild(heart);
}

var hearts = document.getElementsByClassName("heart");
console.log(hearts[9]);
```

```html
<div class="imagebox">
  <a class="heart">&#10084;</a>
</div>
<div class="imagebox">
  <a class="heart">&#10084;</a>
</div>
<div class="imagebox">
  <a class="heart">&#10084;</a>
</div>
<div class="imagebox">
  <a class="heart">&#10084;</a>
</div>
<div class="imagebox">
  <a class="heart">&#10084;</a>
</div>
<div class="imagebox">
  <a class="heart">&#10084;</a>
</div>
<div class="imagebox">
  <a class="heart">&#10084;</a>
</div>
<div class="imagebox">
  <a class="heart">&#10084;</a>
</div>
```

I get in the console that it is undefined.

What I wanted to mention which kinda complicates whole thing is that I created first 8 elements of class heart in html code, and after that, I created another 24 in javascript and gave them all the same class name.

Comment: In your code: if it's in the same block, you can access the element directly via the variable `heart`. No need to comb through the DOM.

Comment: can you give more of your code

Comment: Please provide a _proper_ [mre] of the issue, and not just lines of code that lack context.

Comment: there is one line of code before it which i forgot to write that is in my code as well before fist one:var heart=document.createElement("a");

Comment: My project is very big and to give it whole picture someone new would need hours to grasp it,i know which one is the problem and i will try to compress it as much as i could to give repdroducible example:

Comment: NB: `hearts[9]` is the _tenth_ element.

Comment: Yes,you are right,my mistake but it doesnt change anyhing there is 32 elements

Comment: The code you have currently shown works fine, for up to `console.log(hearts[15])`, after the syntax error it throws because `body` is not defined, is fixed by making that `document.body` instead. https://jsfiddle.net/76sfe5a1/

Comment: Hmm thats intresting,in my original code there is acutally document.body but because of my hastiness i wrote it wrong here.It looks like something else might be a problem.My code has like 10000 lines of code so it is realy hard do diagnose the proble and so far everything worked as expected but since i tried to this it just doesnt work.What if tell you that this javascript is loaded from another file myscript.js and that html is another file would that change anyhing.

Comment: _“What if tell you that […]”_ - then we’d still be left with mainly guesswork again, because that could still mean a lot of things, could still go wrong in one place or other because you got some tiny detail wrong, or or or. We don’t ask for proper _reproducible_ examples for the mere fun of it, but because they are a _necessity_.

Comment: Allright i will make it bigger

Answer (score 0):

I think you should insert **body.appendChild(imagebox)** into the for loop

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
    for (var i = 9; i <= 16; i++) {
      var imagebox = document.createElement("div");
      imagebox.classList.add("imagebox");
      var heart = document.createElement("a");
      heart.innerHTML = "&#10084;";
      heart.classList.add("heart");
      imagebox.appendChild(heart);
      body.appendChild(imagebox);
    }
    var hearts = document.getElementsByClassName("heart");
    console.log(hearts[9]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue,athough i dont understand it,if someone could explain me why this works would be great.

This whole javascript code was inside file all_product.js in that file i this javacript code was wrapped with window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){}),where i created this loop and links.When i put    console.log(hearts[9]); at the bottom of the page it didnt work,but when i putted inside window.addEventListener it works as normal.

Comment: That's because when the page is loaded, the scroll event is not fired so no elements are added to the DOM. After scroll, the hearts are added, so you will be able to access the elements thereafter.

Comment: Thank you for explaination!